# Is it possible to convert 3 Phase 220V to 110V without use of a transformer?

Tags: power, ac, converter, three-phase

I am living in an area where line voltage is 220V. If I have access to all 3 phases, is it possible to create a "socket" with output voltage of ~110V, *without* use of a transformer? This is primarily a thought experiment, rather than a project with definite scope.

Comment: "using only those phases and maybe some simple components as caps or inductors"  You mean like a transformer?

Comment: Nope, the whole point is not to use a transformer. I have no idea if it's possible. I am thinking maybe something like shifting one of the input's phases so that the phase to phase voltage could be 110V.

Comment: What is the reason for not wanting to use a transformer?

Comment: A 2:1 autotransformer is the usual way of deriving a 110 VAC supply from 230VAC. Why do you seek a transformerless solution? (Is this a practical problem, or a thought experiment?)

Comment: A transformer is big and bulky. If it's possible to not use a transformer to do it it would be interesting. It's a thought experiment for now but if it's possible I would want to try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triac based light dimmers do this.

Varying the firing angle of the gate results in a reduced RMS output voltage. The output from this can be rectified and filtered however extreme caution should be exercised because the circuit has no galvanic isolation from the Neutral/Active lines and cannot be earth referenced if ELCB's are intalled.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked all legs against neutral?  Some 3 phase transformers tap so that two legs are 110v.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-leg_delta

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and should perhaps be a comment.